# Creating a validator object from validation factory in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am currently trying to create a validation object in lumen:

```
$validatorFactory = app('Illuminate\Validation\Factory');
$validator = $validatorFactory->make([data], [rules]);
```

However, when I run the code I get back that:

```
 [Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException] Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Validation\Factory, Illuminate\Validation\Factory].
```

This seems to be because no instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator` exists or isn't being created.

Is it not the job of the factory class to do this?

If I do the following:

```
$loader = new FileLoader(new Filesystem, 'lang');
$translator = new Translator($loader, 'en');
$validatorFactory = new Factory($translator, new Container);
```

I can create a new instance of the validator, but this seems overkill.

I know I can use facades but I'm trying to avoid using them since they do not play nice with PHPUnit.